# remove specific value from pyspark array, when that array is produced by `arrays_zip`

Tags: pyspark

Imagine I have a pyspark frame with two array columns, and I zip these columns together using `arrays_zip`.

**How can I subsequently refer to a specific value in the zipped array in order to remove those values?**

Here is an example:

```
edf = (spark
    .createDataFrame([(['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], ['3.0', '2.0', '3.0']),
                      (['rst', 'ghi', 'xyz'], ['4.0', '3.0', '6.0'])])
    .toDF("column_1", "column_2")
       )
edf_zipped = edf.withColumn(
  "zipped", F.arrays_zip("column_1", "column_2")
)
```

I want to remove a specific element - say the element `['ghi','3.0']` from the `zipped` array.  The following code does not work, because I'm not correctly referring to the element.

```
edf_zipped.withColumn("zipped", F.array_remove(F.col("zipped"), ['ghi','3.0']))
```

This is the schema for the zipped column:

```
edf_zipped.select("zipped").schema

StructType(List(StructField(zipped,ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField(column_1,StringType,true),StructField(column_2,StringType,true))),false),true)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want to remove the value by the pair. If not, I will update it.

Your pair is a type of `struct`, so with SQL's `array_remove` you need to convert the values to `struct` with same column names.
(Python's `array_remove` function can only take a simple data as a 2nd argument and won't work on your case)

Using SQL `array_remove`

```
df.withColumn('zipped', F.expr('array_remove(zipped, ("ghi" AS column_1, "3.0" AS column_2))'))
```

or `array_except`. For this, you can use Python's function but the 2nd argument must match the data type of the column of the 1st argument. So, convert the values to an array of struct.

```
df.withColumn('zipped', 
    F.array_except('zipped', 
        F.array(
            F.struct(F.lit('ghi').alias('column_1'), 
                     F.lit('3.0').alias('column_2')
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you try with `array_except` function, by creating a array by using `named_struct` function as shown below.

**Example:**

```
edf = (spark
    .createDataFrame([(['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], ['3.0', '2.0', '3.0']),
                      (['rst', 'ghi', 'xyz'], ['4.0', '3.0', '6.0'])])
    .toDF("column_1", "column_2")
       )
edf_zipped = edf.withColumn("zipped", arrays_zip("column_1", "column_2")).\
selectExpr('zipped', 'array(named_struct("column_1", "ghi", "column_2", "3.0")) as remv_zip').\
withColumn("zipped", array_except(col("zipped"), col("remv_zip")))

edf_zipped.show()
#+------------------------+------------+
#|zipped                  |remv_zip    |
#+------------------------+------------+
#|[{abc, 3.0}, {def, 2.0}]|[{ghi, 3.0}]|
#|[{rst, 4.0}, {xyz, 6.0}]|[{ghi, 3.0}]|
#+------------------------+------------+
```